# Does the series $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\sqrt{n+3}-\sqrt{n+2}\right)$ converge?

Tags: limits

Does 
series  $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\sqrt{n+3}-\sqrt{n+2}\right)$  converge ?

I tried by multiplying it with the conjugate , but can I do that as both tends to infinity can we assure that the difference of these two terms are not zero?

I don't know how to type the exact thing , but cananyone please be kind enough to edit it?

Thank you so much !

Comment: Please improve the notation with MathJax. What do you mean by the infinity symbol? And I'm guessing that with "root", you mean the square root?

Comment: can you please explain me how to do that sir? root means sure root, and n starts from 2 to infinity

Comment: Thank you so much sir @Minus One-Twelfth

Comment: Nope it does not converge! @Minus One-Twelfth practically slayed the beast, consider the first term of the next index of counter, cancels out the second term of the previous index. Just focus a little Bro!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** First find the finite sum $$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{N}\left(\sqrt{n+3}-\sqrt{n+2}\right),$$ then take the limit as $N\to\infty$ to find your answer. To find this finite sum, try writing out several terms and you should see that most terms cancel out. (It is a [telescopic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).)

Comment: so sir ,will  multiplying by the conjugate work ? and there by applying the limit comparison test ?

Comment: That'll work, but seriously, consider reading up on telescoping sequences.

Comment: yes of course sir thank you sir ! But still I can't justify multiplying by the conjugate

Comment: @LasanManujithaUkwaththaLiya Your thinking is too complicated. Try writing out the first, say, five terms of the sum and see what happens to the terms.

Comment: you can multiply by the conjugate in the finite version without restrictions, and then take the limit to infinity, but it's missing the point...

Comment: I learnt about telescope series , thank you so much I'm so grateful @Minus One-Twelfth

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth In this case it is not necessary to obtain the expression for the partial sums, since the general term clearly behaves like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, which leads to a divergent series.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\sum_{n=2}^m(\sqrt{n+3}-\sqrt{n+2})=\sqrt{m+3}-2.$$

Answer (score 1):

To show why your thinking doesn’t work, the $n$th term of the series is

$$(\sqrt{n+3} - \sqrt{n+2}) \cdot \frac{\sqrt{n+3}+\sqrt{n+2}}{\sqrt{n+3} + \sqrt{n+2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+3} + \sqrt{n+2}}$$

which clearly $\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

**However**, the fact that the $n$th term goes to zero does not imply that the series converges—just consider the harmonic series which is well known to diverge. So your technique of ‘multiplying by the conjugate’ (I assume this is what you meant) does not work here.

> Can we assure that the difference of these two terms is not zero?

No, and yet the series still diverges. You can use the techniques given by the other answerers.

Comment: wow , totally cleared every doubt , thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The general term is
$
\sqrt{n+3}-\sqrt{n+2} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+3}+\sqrt{n+2}}.
$
Using the ratio test you can see that this series behaves as $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, which is divergent.

Comment: Thank you sir , I worked out in that way too

Comment: Just curious about the reason of the down vote...This seems the most direct answer.